# Make text from textswitcher go into an array

Tags: android, arrays, listview, settext

I'm trying to get the text from my textswitcher to go into an array.  Basically, whenever a box is clicked, I want the text from the textswitcher to be added to a list.  Also, I have this list being displayed in a listview.  My code looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final List<String> where = new ArrayList<String>();

    mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);

    mSwitcher.setFactory(this);

    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.beta);
    mSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
    mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);

    mSwitcher.setOnClickListener(this);


    ImageView forward = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.forward);
    forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            setContentView(R.layout.listview);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, where));
        }
    });   

    ImageView favorites = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favorite);
    favorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            where.add((String) mSwitcher.getContentDescription());



        }
    });





}
```

If anyone could explain how to do this and why the above code doesn't work, that would be greatly appreciated.